# Adobe Connect API with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-connect

I am trying to create a simple login form for my Adobe Connect account, however it's not working, I'm getting the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
```

However I'm doing other Ajax calls just fine on my machine.

Here's some example code that I'm using.

```
var request $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/api/xml?action=login&login=' + username + '&password=' + password
    type: "GET"
});
request.done(function(){
    ...
})
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local machine calls are working because you're making calls inside the same domain. As soon as you try to do ajax calls to something outside the bounds of the caller's domain you'll run into issues with the browser's Same-Origin policy.

Basically it's a security policy that allows scripts to run on pages originating from the same site (comprised  by the combination between schema, hostname and port. eg. mysite != mysite:8080) So if you have an ajax call executed from a site running on mysite to a site running on mysite:8080, the browser will consider this a same-origin policy hence blocking that request.

You should read about CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in order to find options to help you relax the same-origin policy.